# Java regex for a series of numbers separated with a specific separator

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to describe a string that contains a minimum of three (3) and a maximum of six (6) of 2-digit numbers and 3-digit numbers in any order. The numbers should be separated by `#` but could also contain spaces. Examples of this string are:

```
34 #563# 23

123#678#12#44# 45
```

Comment: Would `1 2 3#456# 7 8 9 ` also be a valid match?

Comment: No, `1 2 3#456# 7 8 9` is not a valid match because not all numbers are separated with #

Comment: It is meant to be used in Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
^s*\d{2,3}\s*(?:#\s*\d{2,3}\s*){2,5}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
\s*       # optional whitespace
\d{2,3}   # match a number (2 to 3 digits)
\s*       # optional whitespace
(?:       # Match...
 \#       # - a hashmark
 \s*      # - optional whitespace
 \d{2,3}  # - a number
 \s*      # - optional whitespace
){2,5}    # 2 to 5 times
$         # End of string
```

Comment: I was going to post the same! You beat me! +1

Comment: Bugger.  That's what I get for typing my explanation before I submit.  Though, for the record, you don't need all the `\s*`s you have.  The original problem statement is a bit vague, but you can combine them.

Comment: It seems that it does the job. Thank you! I will accept that answer if  you just propose the same one but now with the assumption that the separator is the dot `.` and not the hash `#`. How should I escape that?

Comment: @melios: For Java, you need to double each backslash (the Java tag wasn't there yet when I answered the question).

Answer (score 2):

```
/\d{2,3}(?:\s*#\s*\d{2,3}){2,5}/
```

Explanation:

```
\d
```

Capture a digit.

```
{2,3}
```

Two or three times, Then:

(?: ... )

group the following, but don't capture what the group itself captures.

```
\s*
```

Capture zero or more spaces...

```
#
```

... a pound sign.

```
\s*
```

... zero or more spaces...

```
\d{2,3}
```

and another two or three digit number.

```
{2,5}
```

Do that group two to five times, for a total of three to six numbers.

To force it to match a complete string, You can add `^\s*` to the beginning and `\s*$` to the end, as `^` matches the beginning of a string, and `$` the end, but I'd actually recommend using just the carat and dollar sign and using a `trim` function instead, because `\s*` (or really, and `*`) is super inefficient.  Over a string or two, not a big deal, but if you're, say: extracting numbers from a phone book, you're gonna have a bad time.